# I am developing a struts2 application. I want to show the database table on jsp page using list iterator

Tags: database, jsp, struts2

I want to show  the database table e.g. account having attributes accid, accname, accbranch. I have created one DB class inwhich I am writing code to set ResultSet into List. How to do that? and How to show it on the JSP?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-iterator-tag-example1.html)